# Style jQuery autocomplete in a Bootstrap input field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-autocomplete

I have implemented a jQuery autocomplete function to a Bootstrap input. The jQuery autocomplete is working fine but I want to see the results as a combo and I guess it's now happening because I'm using BootStrap.

This is the field that I'm assigning autocomplete:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Employee</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="txtEmployee" placeholder="Trabajador">
</div>
```

```js
$(this).autocomplete({

  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Content("~/Employee/SearchEmployee")/',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
          employerId: 1,
          searchStr: me.val()
      }),
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.success) {

          response($.map(data.data, function(item) {

            return {
              label: "(" + item.EmployeeNumber + ") " + 
                           item.FirstName + " " + 
                           item.MothersLast + ", " + 
                           item.FathersLast,
              employeeId: item.EmployeeId
            }
          }));
        } 
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 3
});
```

The results are displayed but like this:

[image]

How can I style the results with Bootstrap so I can see them like dropdownlist?

Comment: the results are probably converted in a <ul>, but im not sure. Can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Each item in that list has the following html code:
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">(1912) JORGE ORTIZ, NAVA</a></li>

Comment: Well then it should be easy to style with just CSS if you have the class

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you're using jQuery-UI, you *must* include the jQuery UI CSS package, otherwise the UI components don't know how to be styled.

If you don't like the jQuery UI styles, then you'll have to recreate all the styles it would have otherwise applied.

Here's an example and some possible fixes.

### [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. broken)

Here's a demo in Stack Snippets **without** jquery-ui.css (doesn't work)

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
    "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran",
    "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl",
    "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
  ];
  
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Languages</label>
    <input class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Enter A" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >Another Field</label>
    <input class="form-control">
  </div>

</div>
```

### Fix #1 - jQuery-UI Style

Just include jquery-ui.css and everything should work just fine with the latest supported versions of jquery.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
    "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran",
    "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl",
    "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
  ];
  
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Languages</label>
    <input class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Enter A" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >Another Field</label>
    <input class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Fix #2 - Bootstrap Theme

There is a project that created a Bootstrap-esque theme for jQuery-UI components called [jquery‑ui‑bootstrap](https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap).  Just grab the stylesheet from there and you should be all set.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
    "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran",
    "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl",
    "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
  ];
  
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Languages</label>
    <input class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Enter A" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >Another Field</label>
    <input class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Fix #3 - Manual CSS

If you only need the AutoComplete widget from jQuery-UI's library, you should start by doing a custom build so you don't pull in resources you're not using.

After that, you'll need to style it yourself. Just look at some of the other styles that are applied to jquery's [autocomplete.css](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/autocomplete.css) and [theme.css](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/theme.css) to figure out what styles you'll need to manually replace.

You can use bootstrap's [dropdowns.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/dropdowns.less) for inspiration.

Here's a sample CSS that fits pretty well with Bootstrap's default theme:

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.ui-autocomplete > li {
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.ui-autocomplete > li.ui-state-focus {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
    "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran",
    "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl",
    "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
  ];
  
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.ui-autocomplete > li {
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.ui-autocomplete > li.ui-state-focus {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group ui-widget">
    <label>Languages</label>
    <input class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Enter A" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group ui-widget">
    <label >Another Field</label>
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Tip**: Since the dropdown menu hides every time you go to inspect the element (i.e. whenever the input loses focus), for easier debugging of the style, find the control with `.ui-autocomplete` and remove `display: none;`.

Comment: The best answer in regard to jquery dropdown styling, bar none. +1

Comment: The best answer on StackOverflow. Nobel Prize worthy

Comment: In jQuery 1.12, `ui-state-focus` [is now](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#use-consistent-styling-for-focused-and-active-items) `ui-state-active`. Changing `.ui-autocomplete > li.ui-state-focus` to `.ui-state-active` correctly changes the background color when hovering.

Answer (score 18):

Try this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gotemkfr/)):

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.ui-autocomplete > li > div {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-active,
.ui-state-focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Simple & Nice = Thank You

Answer (score 5):

I found the following css in order to style a Bootstrap input for a jquery autocomplete:

https://gist.github.com/daz/2168334#file-style-scss

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    _width: 160px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.ui-menu-item > a.ui-corner-all {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555555;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-state-hover, &.ui-state-active {
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #0088cc;
      border-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0px;
      background-image: none;
    }
```

Comment: Just what i needed. Simple! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The gap between the (bootstrap) input field and jquery-ui autocompleter seem to occur only in jQuery versions >= 3.2

When using jQuery version 3.1.1 it seem to not happen.

Possible reason is the notable update in v3.2.0 related to a bug fix on `.width()` and `.height()`. Check out the jQuery release notes for further details: [v3.2.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out/) / [v3.1.1](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/)

*Bootstrap version 3.4.1 and jquery-ui version 1.12.0 used*

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you fixed it, but I did had the same issue, finally it was a dumb thing, I had:

```
<script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but it should be:

```
<link href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just change `<scrip>` to `<link>` and `src` to `href`

Comment: while this might have been the issue in your particular case, it's not likely it was the issue for OP or other people visiting this particular problem.  So while it's good to note that stylesheets should be added as stylesheets - it probably doesn't warrant a full post to do so. Just FYI