# bootstrap textbox autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I am using this [Bootstrap](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) as my GUI.

I've seen this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285813/style-jquery-autocomplete-in-a-bootstrap-input-field) related to my problem. But when I try the code from the `@KyleMit` I have an error in my console. I got this `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`

[My current Bootstrap](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qay9p49r3330cg3/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.8.rar?dl=0)

**Current Code**

```js
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: "/Controller/Action",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    $(".autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Languages</label>
    <input class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Enter A" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: which js you are including, I means bootstrap and others ? I means, have you included jquery-ui.js ? please check your suggested link's answer for more details

Comment: @rahul_m sorry for the inconvenience. Please take a loot in my edit link.

Comment: And where you want autocomplete ?

Comment: You shouldn't expect people to just download an archive and build your project locally. Instead, use the snippet tool (`<>` button) to create a [mcve] of your problem. From what you describe, you are not including everything needed for jQuery UI to work. You can customize what is included in your jQuery UI package [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I didn't say DL it and build for me. I posted it cuz I forgot the link where did I get it. and rahul ask for jquery's. Instead of typing it I just share the archive.

Comment: @rahul_m I want it in the textbox.

Answer (score 5):

Check this basic example of jquery autocomplete,

JS CODE,

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

Your html,

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Include following code in your head tag,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You can find [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3p2gb7p/3/) here.

Comment: I have a problem with my other jquery. Got conflict here `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Can you post comment here?

Comment: I comment both the JS that is conflict. And the auto complete works. Don't what is the effect yet.

Comment: Very nice & elegant, like it! Btw: how well is this solution supported?

Comment: syntax/words may change version wise, but you can get solution of OP's requirement this way. Are you facing any problem w.r.t different version?