# jQuery UI Autocomplete display while using Bootstrap 5

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

I have a form wrapped in Bootstrap 5 that I'm trying to apply jQuery Autocomplete to.

I've written my jQuery and PHP successfully and it works exactly how I want to it when it's on a basic form with no CSS. However, when I try to apply the working code (with adjustments as necessary) the autocomplete drop-down menu does not appear.

I've seen the post here: [(stackoverflow post) Style jQuery autocomplete in a Bootstrap input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285813/style-jquery-autocomplete-in-a-bootstrap-input-field)

And I've also reviewed the jQuery Autcomplete API Documentation [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Below you'll find the code without any attempt at custom CSS in order to avoid confusion.

---

Excerpt of the form

```
        <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col ms-0 ps-0">
        <h4 class="mt-2">Buyer's Information</h4>
        <hr>
            <div class="row ps-2 pb-2">
                <div class="col pe-2 ps-0">
                    <div class="form-floating mb-0">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buyerFirstName ui-autocomplete" id="buyerFirstName" placeholder="Buyer #1 First Name">
                        <label for="buyerFirstName">Buyer #1 First Name</label>
                    </div>
```

I've also tried adding a div element below the input for the drop-down with no success.

Style and Script tags I'm including:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.2.0.js" integrity="sha256-gvMJWDHjgDrVSiN6eBI9h7dRfQmsTTsGU/eTT8vpzNg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.6/jquery.inputmask.min.js" integrity="sha512-6Jym48dWwVjfmvB0Hu3/4jn4TODd6uvkxdi9GNbBHwZ4nGcRxJUCaTkL3pVY6XUQABqFo3T58EMXFQztbjvAFQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.js" integrity="sha512-TToQDr91fBeG4RE5RjMl/tqNAo35hSRR4cbIFasiV2AAMQ6yKXXYhdSdEpUcRE6bqsTiB+FPLPls4ZAFMoK5WA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css"/>
```

jQuery code for the Autocomplete:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buyerFirstName').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: './autocomplete.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    search: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#buyerFirstName').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#buyerLastName').val(ui.item.value);
            $('#buyerCellPhone').val(ui.item.phone1);
            $('#buyerEmail').val(ui.item.email1);
        }
    });
});
```

And finally the PHP code:

```
<?php 

try {
    require '../config.php';
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $inputQuery = $_POST['search'];

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM buyers WHERE firstName LIKE :firstName';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(['firstName' => '%' . $inputQuery . '%']);

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $response[] = array(
            'value' => $row['firstName'],
            'label' => $row['firstName'] . ' ' . $row['lastName'],
            'lastName' => $row['lastName'],
            'phone1' => $row['phone1'], 
            'email1' => $row['email1'],
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($response); 

} catch (\PDOException $error) {
    throw new \PDOException($error->getMessage(), (int)$error->getCode());
}

?>
```

---

Again, this code all works great when I'm in a test server with no CSS interfering and my main issue is that I'm not getting a dropdown with the autocomplete.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to function properly?

Comment: Are you able to identify the style sheet causing the error, by e.g. applying them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue after moving from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5.

In my case I changed .ui-autocomplete z-index to 99999999 and it worked!

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    ...
    z-index:99999999;
    ...
}
```